# How pass argument from PHP to R script through exec() and use that in R script?

Tags: php, r, exec

I have a problem about PHP and R. I want to call and execute R script from PHP code. But I don't know how to pass arguments through exec() from PHP and how use that arguments in my R script.

This is my PHP code

```
<?php
    exec('C:\\"Program Files"\\R\\R-4.0.3\\bin\\Rscript.exe C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\chatchops\\R_privatChat\\R_TodayOnline.R');
?>
```

this is part of my R script

```
library(dygraphs)
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
library(htmlwidgets)

#get db Connection
mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='', dbname='chatchops', host='localhost', port=3307)

ye <- '2021'
mon <- '10'

    #get data from MySQL database
    query <- paste0("SELECT d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10, d11, d12, d13, d14, d15, d16, d17, d18, d19, d20, d21, d22, d23, d24, d25, d26, d27, d28, d29, d30, d31 FROM `analizeonlineeachmonthd` WHERE recYear = ",ye," AND recMonth = ",mon,";")
    result1 <- dbSendQuery(mydb, query)
    timeData <- fetch(result1)
    dbClearResult(result1)
    
    dbDisconnect(mydb)
```

I want to pass this "ye" and "mon" value from PHP exec function and use it in my R script code. can anyone help me to do this? Or anyone know other method to do this?

Also, I tried these two ways. But not work.

```
<?php
$ye = "2021";  $mon = "10";
  exec('C:\\"Program Files"\\R\\R-4.0.3\\bin\\Rscript.exe C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\chatchops\\R_privatChat\\R_TodayOnline.R' ,$ye ,$mon);
?>
```

In R script

```
library(dygraphs)
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
library(htmlwidgets)

mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='', dbname='chatchops', host='localhost', port=3307)
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
ye <- args[1]
mon <- args[2]
```

and

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
ye <- args[1]
mon <- args[2]
```

Can anyone help me? or can any one give another easy way to do this. The problem occur in when I try to pass argument or when I try to reserve it. Without argument passing this code work fine.

UPDATE

Now it's work. Thank You @Eugene Anisiutkin

```
<?php
exec('C:\\"Program Files"\\R\\R-4.0.3\\bin\\Rscript.exe C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\chatchops\\R_privatChat\\R_TodayOnline.R ' . $ye . ' ' . $mon);
?>
```

In R

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
ye <- args[1]
mon <- args[2]
```

Comment: Both `exec()` and `shell_exec()` just try to execute whatever was provided as a `$command` string, and they both have no `special way` of passing arguments. So basically all the arguments that you want to be passed to executed command have to be contained in this `$command` along with the filename of your R script. Be aware that you actually need  to `Pass arguments to r script from command line`, because on the php side, everything must be in that pesky exec, if you are using exec of course

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin Thank you very much for this answer. I couldn't find another way to do this easily. Still I can't reserve the argument from R script. I don't know the problem happen in PHP side or R side>

Comment: you can always check the php side easily enough - something along the lines of `<?php $test = 'It works'; exec("echo $test > test.txt"); ?>` or really anything like that, I should warn you that this a very fast and very dirty way of checking if the `exec()` actually does what it is supposed to do. Can't help you with R though) know really nothing about it. But if the script runs at all - then it's likely not a php problem

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin Thank you bro. I think that problem in R side.

Comment: Nope, right now it's php side- took a closer look. What I ment by my first comment is than the call has to look like `exec('C:\\"Program Files"\\R\\R-4.0.3\\bin\\Rscript.exe C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\chatchops\\R_privatChat\\R_TodayOnline.R ' . $ye . ' ' . $mon);`. Take notice here the whole command is a single string. `exec()` does have second and third argument actually. The second argument is used to store result of the executed command, and the third stores result code. More detailed description can be found in [Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin Thank you brother. Now it's work . Early I tried also that in wrong way. I missed space after 'R_TodayOnline.R'. Again Thank you very much.